# CActiveForm and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getErrors".

Tags: php, database, yii, authentication

Hi i'm quite new to yii framework, currently trying to establish a login through database authentication. but im repeatedly getting this error

> CException
>
> CActiveForm and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named
>   "getErrors".

can anybody help me out if this

Heres the Controller

```
<?php

class SiteController extends Controller

{

public function actions()
{
    return array(

        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
        ),

        'page'=>array(
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
        ),
    );
}
public function actionIndex()
{

    $this->render('index');
}


public function actionError()
{
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            echo $error['message'];
        else
            $this->render('error', $error);
    }
}


public function actionContact()
{
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->name).'?=';
            $subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->subject).'?=';
            $headers="From: $name <{$model->email}>\r\n".
                "Reply-To: {$model->email}\r\n".
                "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";

            mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$subject,$model->body,$headers);
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
}


public function actionLogin()
{
        $form=new LoginForm;
        if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {
            $form->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
            if($form->validate()  && $form->login()) $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }

            $this->render('login',array('form'=>$form));
}

public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::app()->user->logout();
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
}
```

}

herers the model

```
<?php

class LoginForm extends CFormModel

{
    public $email;
    public $password;


    private $_identity;

public function rules()
    {
        return array(
        array('email, password', 'required'),
        array('email', 'email'),
        array('password', 'authenticate'),
);
    }
public function attributeLabels()
{
            return array('email'=>'Email Address');
}
public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{
            if(!$this->hasErrors())  // we only want to authenticate when no input errors
                {
                $identity=new UserIdentity($this->email,$this->password);
                $identity->authenticate();
                switch($identity->errorCode)
                {
                    case UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE:
                Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
                break;
                    case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID:
                $this->addError('email','Email address is incorrect.');
                break;
        default: // UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID
                $this->addError('password','Password is incorrect.');
                break;
                }
            }
    }
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

}

here the view

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */
/* @var $model LoginForm */
/* @var $form CActiveForm  */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Login';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Login',
);
?>
<h1>Login</h1>

<p>Please fill out the following form with your login credentials:</p>

<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<div>
    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>

    <?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($form); ?>

    <div>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($form,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($form,'email') ?>
    </div>

    <div>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($form,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($form,'password') ?>
    </div>

    <div>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

endWidget(); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be good if you include more of the error - e.g. on which line it occured and in which file, or at best the whole trace..
From what I read in your code it seems that you overwrite the $form variable, which actually hold your model.
In the `SiteController` you initialize the variable `$form` with the `LoginForm` model.
Then in the view you make this wrong call:

```
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'login-form',
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        ),
    )); 
    ?>
```

Therefore in all the CHtml calls you put a widget instead of a model variable to the functions

As you do not use the output of the widget in no specific way, it would be enough to remove the `$form = $this->widget...` and leave it only as `$this->widget..` Or replace the variable for a new one.

```
  <?php $myWidget = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'login-form',
            'enableClientValidation'=>true,
            'clientOptions'=>array(
                'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            ),
        )); 
  ?>
```

Comment: Yii\base\CComponent.php is the script which gives the error... and this is the line which throws the error
throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','{class} and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "{name}".',

Comment: thanks. but in the meantime i am 99% sure the problem is as I described it. You overwrite you model variable woth the widget, and that of course has no method to check errors. please try my solution