# Upload and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getErrors"

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I am trying to build a form which would upload an image to the server.
So I have 3 files.

1. Model Upload.php

   ```
   <?php
   class Upload extends CActiveForm
   {
       public $image;

       public function rules()
       {
           return array(
               array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
           );
       }
   }
   ```
2. View Upload.php

   ```
   <div class="box">
       <div class="body">
           <header class="clearfix">
               <div class="icons"><i class="icon-picture"></i></div>
               <h5 class="pull-left">Upload Your Memes</h5>
           </header>
           <div class="form">
               <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm'); ?>

               <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
               <?php echo $form->label($model,'image'); ?>
               <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'image') ?><br>
               <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
               <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Controller.php

   ```
   <?php
   class MemeController extends AdminController {
       public function actionUpload() {
           $model=new Upload();
           if(isset($_POST['image']))
           {
               $model->attributes=$_POST['image'];
               $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
               if($model->save())
               {
                   $model->image->saveAs('/volume1/web/memes/templates/test.png');
                   $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
               }
           }
           $this->render('upload', array('model'=>$model));
       }
   }
   ```

Any ideas on why I am getting 
Error 500
MemeUpload and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getErrors".
?
I have tried suggestions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035950/cactiveform-and-its-behaviors-do-not-have-a-method-or-closure-named-geterrors) link however that doesn't really help.
All I'm getting after those changes is another error which is:
Upload Your Memes

Fatal error: Call to a member function errorSummary() on a non-object in /volume1/web/website/protected/modules/admin/themes/admin/views/meme/upload.php on line 10

where line 10 is 
`<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>`

Any ideas what else can I try?

Comment: I changed code to <?php echo CHtml::form('','post',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')); ?>
                <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image'); ?><br>
                <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
                <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>

                <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['image'])) {
                        echo $_POST['image'];
                    } else {
                        echo 'No Image';
                    }
                ?> and I don't get any errors anymore however it doesn't recognize post items. why?

Comment: I just get 'No Image' every time even after I press submit.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I think you should have error filed below your file field as 

    `echo $form->fileField($model,'image');
echo $form->error($model,'image');`

Comment: This then gives error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fileField() on a non-object in /volume1/web/website/protected/modules/admin/themes/admin/views/meme/upload.php on line 10

Comment: try to add  'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' as -
**
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
));**

Comment: Thank you. Form seems to be loading now. Could you please explain why it had to be done this way?
** Edit ** Actually, no sorry, still doesn't work. Getting error: Upload and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "hasErrors".

Comment: Guys please? anyone? I'm really new to Yii :(

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue for now.
I just used standard HTML form tags rather than using the ones that Yii provide.
This kind of fixed all of the errors that I had.